# Data from excel to sql tabel is importing in NULL values...why??

Tags: c#, sql, excel

I am importing data from excel to database.
Following is schema of excel columns:
below is the schema of db....and exactly matches with excel sheet data....................

```
ID  integer                 
organizationId  integer             
categoryId  integer         
attribute   text          
Y1960       integer or null     
Y1961       integer or null      
Y1962       integer or null       
Y1963       integer or null      
Y1964       integer or null     
Y1965       integer or null       
Y1966       integer or null      
Y1967       integer or null       
Y1968       integer or null      
Y1969       integer or null
```

And same is in database columns. I am using following code to retrieve 
data of `first 10 columns  from excel` file.

```
OleDbConnection excelConnection =
                        new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);

        //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
        ("Select [ID],[organizationID],[categoryID],[parentID],[granularityLevel],[attribute],[Y1960],[Y1961],[Y1962],[Y1963],[Y1964],[Y1965] from [Details$]", excelConnection);

        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString);
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Data";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
```

Problem is that data of `Y1960 column is not copied` into database table from excel file.
Other columns are copied, but Y1960 is not copied. Only null value is available there.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue a few times in the past, the solution I found was to make the destination datatype a float.  There's a suggestion here to stage the data first, and then convert which could also be an option [Error converting data types when importing from Excel to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808371/error-converting-data-types-when-importing-from-excel-to-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

i hope `Y1960` is first row of your excel sheet.

when you doing this copy task at that time `first excel sheet row take as title of column` that's why this row should not copied. you have to add one more row with title at top of your sheet than you can try it.

Comment: @asim What is id ?
can you give me detail of your excel sheet format ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with two columns not getting copied properly instead it was inserting null values. What resolved my issue was making the HDR=NO in the extended properties.
Making all the columns as Varchar. It worked for my scenario since I was ok with doing everything as VC in SQL

Thanks,
TP

Answer (score 0):

My mixed data was appearing as Null when moving it from excel to Sql table. To resolve this Add IMEX option in your connection string for the excel. It tells the driver to always read "intermixed" data columns as text.

Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\MyExcel.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""