# Potential lost conversion from double to int (Excel to SQL Server import)

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have been looking around this solution, but this doesn't work for me either the solutions on the bottom:
[Error converting data types when importing from Excel to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808371/error-converting-data-types-when-importing-from-excel-to-sql-server-2008)

I have an excel file with 3 columns, the last one have numbers. I want to import it to a SQL database, the problem is matching that last columns with the Destination Type.
To keep in mind, i can't convert to double my Destination Type, because is a foreign key of a Int.

So the question is:
How can i format a column in excel to int or a solution to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Import the data into a staging table with column type decimal or float then convert it to int and the do an insert into your table from that staging table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't implicit format to int in Excel.
There is another solution that work for me:

1) Save your Excel table as .txt file.

2) Now open your SQL Server Management Studio -> Import Data to your Database.

3) In Data source select Flat File Source, look for your .txt file -> In the left side go to Advanced. You will have to manually select de DataType for each column, example:

*For string select: string [DT_STR]

*For int select: single-byte signed integer [DT_I1]

Click Next and follow your normal process to import it