# Uploading excel file to sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2014

While i upload my file in sql server, the fields with long number values automatically change the data to exponential data. either the field type is varchar or int in the database but it transforms the data to exponential data..This number 4308007808 has changed to 4.30801e+009. is there any solution?

```
  INTO FEED_TEMP_TABLE 
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
         'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\\TestData\\PRS_AGENT_VZ.xlsx;HDR=YES', [Sheet1$])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error converting data types when importing from Excel to SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808371/error-converting-data-types-when-importing-from-excel-to-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Yes its a similar issue, the issue was that i was casting my integer type to varchar, then it was changing to exponential form, when i stopped casting it, it's working fine now.